# Print Line Number in Matlab

Tags: matlab, debugging

I have a Matlab function which runs into few thousands of lines of code. Under certain condition, it is breaking. I can as well, debug the code and run step-by-step.

So, I have try, catch block in Matlab to handle the error. In addition to this, is it possible to capture, the line number of the code as well.

For Example :

```
try
 Error here <-----
catch err
disp(['Error occured on line No ' num2str(lineNo])
end
```

Any idea, how it can be implemented ?

Answer (score 4):

Try this. This will print out the line numbers along with the full stack.

```
try
    %some code;
catch exc
    getReport(exc, 'extended')
end
```

Comment: Let me try this.. Thanks a lot Harshal

Answer (score 2):

You may also consider using

```
>> dbstop if error
```

before running the code: this way when an error occurs, Matlab creates a debug breakpoint and allow you to debug at the error.

Comment: If the error is occurring inside the try/catch, they'll need `dbstop if all error`.

Comment: @Edric indeed, My intension was to replace the `try`-`catch` with `dbstop if error`, since it is only for debug purposes...

Comment: @Edric Is `if all error` documented? I can only find `if error` and `if caught error` in the doc. If I haven't missed something, perhaps that should be documented?

Comment: Hm, I think `if all error` appears to be the same as `if caught error`. But with less typing.

Comment: `dbstop if all error` used to be documented in older versions of Matlab. Its behavior is the union of `if error` and `if caught error`. Don't know if it's deprecated or this is just an oversight in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

You can try in this way:

```
try
  Error here <--------------
catch err
    disp([err.identifier]);
    disp([err.message]);
    for e=1:length(err.stack)
       disp(['Error in ' err.stack(e).file ' at line ' num2str(err.stack(e).line)]); 
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

To print the line number you can use this command:

`printf(['Line number '  num2str(dbstack.line) '\n'])`